# SQL Server last insert id return array in CodeIgniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

i'm using sqlsrv driver in CI
However, when i use the $this->db->insert_id() it returns me an array

I'm doing this in the controller after a db insert

Error Number: 42S22

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Array'.

Anybody can help?
Thanks alot

```
Model
function insert_message($data)
{
 $this->db->insert('message', $data);
 $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
 return $last_id;
}   

Controller
$message = $this->Message->insert_message(
$data = array(
        'admin_account_id'        => $accountid,
        'message_subject'     => $subject,
        'message_content'     => $content,
        'message_priority'    => $priority,
        'date_send'           => $date_send,
        'message_status'      => $status,
        'message_createddate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'message_send_usergroup'=> $usergroup
    );

);


Database driver (sqlsrv_driver.php)
function insert_id()
{

    return $this->query('select @@IDENTITY as insert_id')->row('insert_id');
}
```

the $data does not include the identity column.
This is the code i'm using now but i'm still getting an Array from $last_id.

Comment: Database interaction should only happen in models. This might also help solve your problem as there could be more queries between the insert in the model and when you call the function insert_id.

Comment: i've changed the code to be in the Model but i still get an Array

Comment: well, what's in there? var_dump($last_id); -- and are you sure the error doesn't come from the insert itself, your description is kind of vague. how does $data look like?

Comment: the $data is an array of values. and the data is inserted into the database

Comment: Try a `var_dump($last_id);die();` and show us whats in the array.

Comment: Did you modify the driver's code?  According to the [stable branch](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php#L280), it should be `return $this->query('select @@IDENTITY as insert_id')->row('insert_id');`.

Comment: the vardump is array(0) { },i have changed back   `return $this->query('select @@IDENTITY as insert_id')->row('insert_id');`

Comment: You could try the implementation of the [developement's branch](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php#L251).  I do find `->row('insert_id')` an odd syntax and the dev's branch doesn't seems odd to me.

Comment: I've changed it to the development code. But now it returns `NULL`

Comment: Sounds stupid, but I need to ask, is your message actually inserted into your database?

Comment: yes it is inserted. the message_id is the identity column. its not in the $data array. i want to retrieve the last inserted message_id

Comment: and the identity is set as an autoincrement in the DB?

Comment: yes it is auto increment

Comment: var_dump on query. `object(CI_DB_sqlsrv_result)#23 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(32) of type (SQL Server Connection) ["result_id"]=> resource(49) of type (SQL Server Statement) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> bool(false) ["row_data"]=> NULL } array(0) { }`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

you would replace with :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('<table_name>') as last_id");
$res = $query->result();
return $res[0]->last_id;
```

This is a provisional solution.