# Database structure possibility

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, odbc

I have a question about databases and I'm using active recordsCodeigniter.

The logic is like this: I have a table, let's say its name is A, table A has 4 fields, such as: uniqueID, typeofID, date, and userID.

First step: I (user) do validation with table A with condition uniqueID and typeofID. If the row is true or uniqueID is available, then it returns success.

Second step: If the validation was successful, then the user can insert the data into a new table, let's say table is B. In table B there's id with extra A.I (auto increament). In table B there are 4 fields: id, username, question1, question2.

The question is: can I insert table B id into field userID table A? 
This way, when someone accesses table A, he will know what is the username in table A by knowing the userID.

=========================================================================

the solution from the members, already successful. 
first i insert data to table B using table a uniqueID and get the last id, after that insert the data.

this is my solution

```
$this->db->insert('tableB', $data);
$result  = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->where('uniqueID', $data2['uniqueID']);
$result2 = $this->db->update('tableA', array('idfromtableB' => $result));

return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

but i had error with insert_id() in odbc. the error says:
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined property: CI_DB_odbc_driver::$db

Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php

Line Number: 239

Backtrace:

```
<p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\application\models\users_m.php
    <br />
        Line: 79
    <br />
        Function: insert_id         
</p>
```

=========================================================================

Found the solution here: [SQL Server last insert id return array in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485189/sql-server-last-insert-id-return-array-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inserting to table B, use `$user_id = $this->db->insert_id()` to get the last insert ID (table B's ID) and then update table A. So your code looks like

```
...
$this->db->insert('tableA',$data);
$last_rowID = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->insert('tableB',$dataB);
$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->where('tableA_ID',$last_rowID )->update('tableA',array('userID' => $user_id));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't insert the data into tableA, I'm just check whether the data is true or false. If false the validation will not success. If success then i can continue to insert data to tableB and update tableA. What if, I'm just use 3 line to down ( i mean insert tableB and insert_id() ) @rejoanul-alam

Comment: So you can get the table A's that row ID (for which success returns) & now your $last_rowID will be `$last_rowID = $success[0]['row_ID']` and then update table A. All you have to do is get the table A's row ID. got idea now?

Comment: yeah i know what you mean.but, table A already fill with data. i don't insert any data to it. so what if table A data has 27 id, and table B is 0?  after thinking a wile, i guess this is imposible without condtion . @rejoanul-alam

Comment: so it clear that your userID has null/no data against tableB. So if data not inserted to table B make `$last_rowID  = null;` Hope it will solve now

Comment: hi @rejoanul-alam,  i already used insert id. i have q question. why i can't the id when i use odbc ? the error says: `<p>Message:  Undefined property: CI_DB_odbc_driver::$db</p>` complete error is in my thread above.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, you just need to join your tables :

For example :

```
public function get_info($id){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tableA');
  $this->db->join('tableB' ,tableA.id=tableB.id);
  $this->db->where('tableA.id' , $id);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result_array(); 

}
```

kindly modify it so will fit in your code.

Comment: can i insert first data first into table B and then insert table ID into column userID table A ? @xammeil

Comment: yes you can,,,  so this means that you will have a foreign key in your table A. You need to put another column in table A to specify the id on table B and use this as a connection in your tables.